# require is called earlier as import statement

Tags: browserify, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I've got a module `m1` that needs to be initialized before I can import a module `m2`:

```
import * as m1 from 'm1';
m1.init(...)
import * as m2 from 'm2';
```

I updated `browserify` and switched from `6to5ify` to `babelify` transformer. Afterwards, `require` calls in my bundle got moved to the top:

```
...
var _m1 = require('./m1');
var m1 = _interopRequireWildcard(_m1);
var _m2 = require('./m2');
var m2 = _interopRequireWildcard(_m2);
m1.init('init value');
...
```

Why are `require` calls moved to the top? Can I use ES6 module import syntax to import `m2` after `m1.init` is called? I can use `require` directly

```
import * as m1 from 'm1';
m1.init(...)
const m2 = require('m2');
```

and I get

```
var _m1 = require('./m1');
var m1 = _interopRequireWildcard(_m1);
m1.init('init value');
var m2 = require('./m2');
```

but that seems like a hack to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I use ES6 module `import` syntax to import `m2` after `m1.init` is called?

Irrespectively how Babel transpiles this code, the answer is: **no**. The spec dictates that all dependencies are evaluated *before* the module itself is evaluated ([§15.2.1.16.5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-moduleevaluation)).

That means that `import` declarations are not evaluated when engine actually executes the code. They are statically analyzed and this information is somehow added to the module, so that the dependencies can be evaluated before the module itself is evaluated.

---

Even if you found a transpiler that would do what you want, it would not be spec compliant and your code could potentially break in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Imports should be thought of as hoisted values in ES6. They are always at the top of the module. You are currently relying on an implicit dependency. If `m2` relies on `m1` not only being loaded, but also being initialized, then you should have a module that explicitly returns an initialized version of `m1`, then it should be depending on that explicitly or via import ordering if you can't directly modify `m2`, e.g.

#### init-m1.js

```
import * as m1 from 'm1';
m1.init(...)
export default m1;
```

#### init-m2.js

```
import m1 from './init-m1';
import * as m2 from 'm2';
```